# Java multi client game server

Tags: java, server, serversocket

I am having trouble making a multi client server for a game that i have made. I am able to create a ServerSocket, make a connection and send data through means of a ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream. My problems lies when it comes to multiple clients, from what i understand a new thread needs to be created for each client but the data i would like to send and receive is hard coded into the client class. How would I allow my Client to send changeable data?

Here is my client class:

```
 public class Client extends Thread {
private Server server = new Server();
private Socket connection;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;

public Client(Socket connection) {
    this.connection = connection;

    this.out = server.objOutStream(this.connection);
    this.in = server.objInStream(this.connection);
}

public void run() {
    while(this.connection.isConnected()) {
        //
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("hello there");
        server.sendData(out, list);
        //
        List<String> recive = new ArrayList<String>();
        recive = server.reveiveData(in);
    }
}

public Socket getConnection() {
    return connection;
 }
}
```

and Here is the server side:

```
public ServerSocket createServer(Integer serverPort, Integer serverSize) {
    ServerSocket server = null;
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(serverPort, serverSize);
        System.out.println("created server");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return server;
}

public Socket makeConnection(ServerSocket server) {
    Socket connection = null;
    try {
        connection = server.accept();
        Client client = new Client(connection);
        client.start();
        System.out.println("connection made with " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public ObjectInputStream objInStream(Socket connection) {
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}

public ObjectOutputStream objOutStream(Socket connection) {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return out;
}

public void sendData(ObjectOutputStream out, List<String> list) {
    try {
        out.writeObject(list);
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("sending " + list);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<String> reveiveData(ObjectInputStream in) {
    List<String> list = null;
    try {
        list = (List<String>) in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}

public Socket joinServer(String serverIP, Integer serverPort) {
    Socket connection = null;
    try {
        connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), serverPort); System.out.println("joined");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}

public void stop(Socket connection) {
    System.out.println("closing");
    try {
        if(connection.isInputShutdown() == false) {
            connection.getInputStream().close();
        }
        if(connection.isOutputShutdown() == false) {
            connection.getOutputStream().close();
        }
        if(connection.isConnected() == true) {
            connection.close();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my mian class I run this:

```
        try {
        if(connection == null) {
            connection = server.makeConnection(serverSocket);
            in = server.objInStream(connection);
            out = server.objOutStream(connection);
        }else {
            //readlist
            List<String> readList = (List<String>) in.readObject();
            System.out.println("reciving: " + readList);

            //writelist
            List<String> writeList = new ArrayList<String>();
            writeList.add("hi");
            out.writeObject(writeList);
            System.out.println("sending: " + writeList);
        }
    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I'm going to give you my honest thoughts about this: networking is hard; there are many ways to go about this, but I'm afraid that your question regarding how to allow your client to send data dynamically is too broad for SO.  I recommend you take a look at a project of mine where I've done most of the work for you (https://github.com/jhg023/SimpleNet).  Feel free to add the Discord that's listed on my profile or start a chat with me on here if you run into any issues.

Comment: thank you very much